# How to run Spark python code in Jupyter Notebook via command prompt

Tags: python, bigdata, apache-spark, pyspark, data-engineering

I am trying to import a data frame into spark using Python's pyspark module. For this, I used Jupyter Notebook and executed the code shown in the screenshot below

[image]

After that I want to run this in CMD so that I can save my python codes in text file and save as test.py (as python file). Then, I run that python file in CMD using python test.py command, below the screen shot:

[image]

So my task previously worked, but after 3 or 4 hours later I again tried to execute the same process, with no changes made...Then unfortunately I got the following error message:

Can someone please explain why this has happened?

Many thanks in advance

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First time when you executed your code, you might have executed it from the same location where your `te.csv` file was present.

Are you executing this code in the same location as before? If not, then I suggest you put in and reference the absolute path of `te.csv` in your code. This should then run without a hitch.